# Paying a bookstore to stock your self-published book

Tags: sales

A local bookstore has decided to charge $35 to stock my book for 6 months.  For each book sold, they get 40%  and I get 60%.  The stocking charge is new.  Is this common and reasonable?

Answer (score 3):

If the store gets 40% of the sale price, with a guaranteed minimum of $35 over 6 months, then that sounds reasonable.  After all, it costs them money to provide you with shelf space, whether your book sells or not.  But 40% PLUS the $35 seems unfair.  To me.  It seems like they don't want to run any risk of your book being a flop, but they also want to benefit in case the book is a hit.  I'd bargain for a better deal, or find another bookstore.  However, I'm not an expert on local bookstore policies.  You might try selling it as an e-book first.  A proven seller should merit a better deal.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about the bookstore industry specifically, but stocking fees are pretty common in the retail business (at least in the US).